# Mosaic tool not licensed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, mosaic, license

I am very new to ArcGIS Desktop in general, and am having trouble stiching several rasters together. I know that the mosaic tool can do this, but when I try to create a new mosaic dataset I get the error message:

> you do not have the necessary license to execute the selected tool.

The Spatial Analyst extension is turned ON, and I have checked it several times, and it is otherwise working.

Is there something else besides the Spatial Analyst I need?

Comment: this help says it is available at all license levels: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000097000000

Comment: The Mosaic tool you referenced is in the Raster Dataset toolset. I believe @user19084 is using Mosaic Datasets. Tools in that toolset do need Editor or Info as Zachary points out. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Mosaic_Dataset/00170000008n000000/ It can be a little confusing that the names are so similar, but there are differences in these 2 types

Answer (score 3):

You need either an ArcEditor or ArcInfo license level to use the mosiac tool.  You can use ArcGIS Adminstrator to verify and change your license level.  First close ArcMap, then go to Programs>ArcGIS>ArcGIS Adminstrator. Select the Desktop folder, then check your level on the right.  If ArcView is selected you will need to change to an ArcEditor or ArcInfo level license if they are available to you.  Simply select the new license level and click Ok.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, it appears I have ArcView, which is why I cannot use the tool.